# Javascript Looping through object values and changing the css based on value

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I am writing a script that loops through an object to first get the elements and then I am trying to loop through the value of the elements so i can change the CSS.  Here is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var carParts = {
    doors: {
        flDoor: 'LOCKED',
        blDoor: 'LOCKED',
        frDoor: 'LOCKED',
        brDoor: 'LOCKED'
    }
}
var lights = 'OFF';
if (lights === 'OFF') {
    $('.lights').css("display", "none");
}

for(var i in carParts.doors) {
    for(var key in carParts.doors) {
        var value = carParts.doors[key];
        console.log(value);
        if (value === 'locked') {
            $('.'+i+'-open').css("display", "none");
        }
    }
}
})
```

So i want to loop through the carparts.door object and get the actual flDoor, blDoor, frDoor, brDoor.  These names are needed in the final jquery line to assign the proper class name.  I don't want that line to fire unless the actual value is locked though.  I'm newer to javascript and still learning.  I appreciate any feedback you have on the code.

Comment: `var lights = 'OFF';
if (lights === 'OFF')` should just be `if(true)` `;)`

Comment: And you seem to be comparing uppercase `LOCKED` against the string `locked` within the `for...in` loop: JavaScript is case-sensitive, you need to pay attention to that (or use `.toLowerCase()` in string-comparisons).

Comment: Awesome thanks, I changed those aspects.  Now with the proper case in the loop statement I was expecting it to one by one do the check and change the css.  It looks as if it is going through and if any one of the values is LOCKED it is assigning everything a display: none style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>**[Working FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/gS7FV/)**</kbd>

The `LOCKED` is in uppercase. You are comparing with the lowercase. Try this:

```
if (value === 'LOCKED') {
    //
}
```

And why you have two loops? One is enough.

### HTML

```
<div class="flDoor-open">flDoor</div>
<div class="blDoor-open">blDoor</div>
<div class="frDoor-open">frDoor</div>
<div class="brDoor-open">brDoor</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
$(function () {
    var carParts = {
        doors: {
            flDoor: 'OPENED',
            blDoor: 'OPENED',
            frDoor: 'LOCKED',
            brDoor: 'LOCKED'
        }
    };

    for (var key in carParts.doors) {
        var value = carParts.doors[key];

        if (value === 'LOCKED') {
            $('.' + key + '-open').css("display", "none");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks as well, David above you said the same thing and I commented if anyone else has any other thoughts.

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you.  As I said a bit new to javascript so working out the best method for the code and how to write it still is difficult.  This solution fixed everything and If i could rate up I would.